# Nginx/PHP-FPM "Access denied." error

Tags: 12.04, php, nginx, php-fpm

I'm trying to set up a freshly installed Ubuntu (12.04) server, but I can't get PHP files running through php-fpm. No matter what I do, I always get a "Access denied." page (plain text, not html or anything).

**Installed packages:**

```
nginx
nginx-common
nginx-full
php5
php5-cli
php5-common
php5-fpm
```

**Configuration details:**

PHP-FPM:

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

Nginx:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 3;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
```

Default/test domain:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /extra/htdocs/default;
    index        index.html index.php

    access_log   /extra/logs/default/access.log;
    error_log    /extra/logs/default/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php
    {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

/extra/htdocs/default/index.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Everything else is default. Both the Nginx and php-fpm logs show no errors. Yet when I load `http://<server-ip>/index.php` I get the "Access denied" page.

**Troubleshooting:**

- The index.html file works just fine. Therefore it must be either php-fpm, or the fastcgi binding between Nginx and php-fpm.
- I've set the ownership (both user and group) of the entire `/extra` directory to `www-data`, and ownership to 777, just to be sure (I'll tone it down once it works of course). So it's certainly not a permissions issue
- It's not the [security.limit_extensions](http://ffct.cc/solving-nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-issue/) issue that I see a lot: by default that is set to .php, which is exactly what I'm requesting. I've explicitly set it to `.php .html`, with the same result.

I'm really getting tired of this, I've installed this setup twice already (albeit on OSX machines), and everything worked flawlessly. Is there anything I'm overlooking?

**The log contents:**

The Nginx error log is empty.

Nginx access log (removed ip):

```
<ip> - - [17/Jul/2012:11:21:25 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
<ip> - - [17/Jul/2012:11:21:28 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
<ip> - - [17/Jul/2012:11:21:34 +0200] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

php-fpm log:

```
[17-Jul-2012 10:44:14] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 4969
[17-Jul-2012 10:44:14] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally fixed it.

The culprit was this line in my config:

```
fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED     $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
```

If I commented this line, everything worked fine. However I saw this in almost every post I read about Nginx configs, so it bothered me. When looking at my configs for the millionth time, I saw that `cgi.fix_pathinfo` (in `php.ini`) was set to 0, where it should have been 1. The default value PHP uses is also 1, so I must have changed this in my debugging hours, because I remember reading about this value, and thought it was set correct.

Anyway, maybe it helps anyone Googling for this issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. It's recommended [not to trust the tutorials](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/) as those tutorials may contains unsecured configurations. Those configurations may still work correctly, though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I came across that a couple of times and have applied those instructions. The mistake was probably my own in my debugging rage (after x hours you start to lose track of some of the things you have altered).

Comment: Mine was a `chown` issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. Been working on this problem for hours and `cgi.fix_pathinfo` set to 0 (default configuration) was the problem.

Comment: `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0` is recommended by a lot of tutorials because it helps mitigate vulnerabilities, specifically vulnerabilities executing php code through arbitrary files. So if you do set this to 1 **make sure you know what you are doing** or specify other mitigations to make up for it. I found this post to have a good explanation on the issue: https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu and openSUSE, the access denied error could also be related to AppArmor. You can easily check this by running:

```
sudo grep -i denied /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

If you get something like this, it's AppArmor:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1678543274.258:837): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="php-fpm" name="/srv/www/htdocs/test.php" pid=31787 comm="php-fpm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=487 ouid=1000
```